# Done button in UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

in my tableViewController, the user can press Edit on the left, delete data, then if he push "Done" or press back navigation button happens the same thing.

Should i block back button until he doesn't press Done right?

How can i procede?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the edit button as your `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, then it will hide the back button and your user will not be able to pop the navigation stack preemptively.  So I think you're already set -- just wire up the Done button to do `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.